# Short story about two spaceships moving in opposite directions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a sci fi short story:

- It is told in a slightly surreal dreamscape kind of way.
- Two identical spaceships are headed in opposite directions, each carrying a solitary person one of whom is our first person narrator.
- As they get further and further apart the narrator starts to feel closer and closer to their counterpart, as if they could just walk round a corner and bump into them.  They're possibly in love with their counterpart?  But it's not clear.
- The narrator is very lonely and it is implied that they are gradually becoming less sane
- I don't think the purpose of the mission is ever made clear, nor does the character have a name and I'm not sure their gender is even specified.
- It is made clear that they will never see their counterpart again, but not made clear why.  Much is made of the fact that the two ships are identical, which makes the narrator feel as if their counterpart is really there with them.
- I think I either read or heard this after 2012.  I'm tending towards heard, either on the radio (BBC radio 4?) or a podcast.  If I read it, I read it online I think, not in an anthology.

Sorry I don't have more to go on!

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Thanks!  I've tried my best but I can't remember anything else right now