# Two sorcerers duel whose willpower increases with distance

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read more than 20 years ago, but I don't recall at all where.

It opens with a pair of sorcerers (with innate, mental-based powers like telekinesis) competing.  One pulls down some rocks from space at the other, and the target just barely manages to deflect them.

It is revealed that their mental powers are stronger the farther away they are exerted.  Thus it's easier to yank rocks out of space hundreds of kilometres away than it is to deflect them just a few kilometres away.

The two aren't really friends, but there's a certain amount of respect and camaraderie between them; they may be the two most powerful in the world, and it's basically by competing that they stave off boredom.

Somehow the idea comes up that if they are so powerful at short range, they would be vastly more powerful at huge range.  Each of them wraps the other in a shell of protection and then starts pushing the other away.  If I'm remembering correctly, by the time each had reached the opposite end of the field they were in they were able to levitate the other.  And they kept pushing.

Fast forward years (I'm probably missing bits of the story here) and they are (literally) light years apart; each is able to accelerate the other with *immense* power and still keep the other protected from the effects.  Their [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) is huge, and time is flitting by on the world they left behind.

(This question was inspired by [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231976/short-story-about-two-spaceships-moving-in-opposite-directions) about two connected people moving apart.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "The Blink of a Wizard's Eye" by Joel Rosenberg, published in [Dragon #71](https://thetrove.net/Books/Dungeons%20&%20Dragons/Magazines/Dragon/051-100/Dragon%20Magazine%20-%20071.pdf).  (I previously identified it [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151392/story-about-two-wizards-from-earths-past-who-go-on-relativistic-trips-through-s/175796#175796).)

Here is the information about wizards' powers getting greater with distance (and one of them pulling the rocks being pulled down from space, although the target is not actually the other wizard):

> One of the peasants shouted, pointing toward the sky.  As Lohim concentrated, the remnants of the crowd broke and ran.  Lohim shook his head, tsking. Normals, faced with an angry wizard, always seemed to forget the direct square law that governed magical spells: The farther away a wizard is from an object, the more control he has over it, and vice versa.  Logic would have dictated that the normals try to escape Lohim’s spell by running toward the tavern, toward Lohim.  But logic
> evaporated quickly in panic — and the mob fled.  Now the rocks were only half a mile up.

At the end, they decide to move farther and father away from each other, increasing their power, with a wink to nuclear power:

> At a butterfly’s-breath short of the speed of light, they sped further and further, faster and faster from their home world.
>
> The situation on the planet precisely halfway between them got no better; a world is ill served by being the plaything of two wizards
>
> Once, in between Cipher-protected breaths, Lohim acted on a sudden impulse to set up an independent source of power on Earth, a power that might be able to clean up the mess the two wizards had made.  It didn’t work; Cipher had anticipated the move, and he turned Lohim’s power into the cause, rather than the cure, of wars and persecutions and murders.
>
> From the two wizards’ viewpoints, time continues to speed up, so that neither of them can quite follow what is going on, here on Earth, any more; both are dazzled by the speed at which changes take place.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you!  Weird that it isn't even listed in ISFDb though.  (I guess my brain latched onto the wrong keywords; I didn't find the previous question.)